# WIX - Custom actions on Install but not on Uninstall or Upgrade

Tags: wix

I have a wix installer where we have several Custom Actions running, like the registration etc. However we only want these to run on the Install, not on the upgrade or the uninstall.

I've tried setting it to NOT Installed AND REINSTALL but that isn't working either.

Does anyone know what the correct property is when wanting to run certain apps via custom action only on Install and not on Upgrade or uninstall?

```
 <InstallExecuteSequence>
     <Custom Action="PosConfig.CustomAction" Before="StartServices"><![CDATA[NOT Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE AND UILevel>3]]></Custom>
     <Custom Action="Register.CustomAction" After="PosConfig.CustomAction">NOT Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE </Custom>
     <Custom Action="OPOSSelectorFirst.CustomAction" After="Register.CustomAction"><![CDATA[NOT Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE AND &ProductFeature=3 AND Not OPOSDLLINSTALLED]]></Custom>
     <Custom Action="OPOSSelectorUpdate.CustomAction" After="OPOSSelectorFirst.CustomAction"><![CDATA[NOT Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE AND &ProductFeature=3 AND Not OPOSDLLINSTALLED]]></Custom>
  </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

EDIT: Added my Custom Action Sequence.

Comment: `NOT INSTALLED` should be fine (I assume that you didn't write it with the spelling mistake in your code). Please show your `InstallExecuteSequence` where you actually schedule the custom action.

Comment: Added the Code example, We normally have it set to NOT Installed, however that doesn't seem to work as it still runs the custom actions on Upgrade

Comment: Do you have the log file to analyze the value for your condition to work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`NOT Installed AND REINSTALL` can never be true at the same time. That would mean the application is not installed but is currently being re-installed. How would that work?

Schedule your custom action by using this condition instead:

`NOT Installed AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE`

This prevents it from being triggered on major upgrades.

Comment: I have just tried this solution, however it still shows the applications during the upgrade from one version to another.

Comment: @Lex: Which CA gets called? `Register.CustomAction`?

Comment: I tried it on all of them, as we really don't want to see them at all on an upgrade, however every single one of them still showed up.

Comment: @Lex: This has always been an issue with Windows Installer. Depending on your `Upgrade` section you can use the properties set there - but only if `OnlyDetect` is set to yes, otherwise that won't work either. You can try `NOT INSTALLED AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE AND NOT REINSTALL`. As far as I remember `REINSTALL` is not set during a major upgrade though - but you can try.

Comment: Properties are case sensitive. Use Installed, not INSTALLED.

Answer (score 4):

UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE is set during the RemoveExistingProducts action. Depending on your `MajorUpgrade Schedule` it may be too late. I've come to solution `NOT Installed AND NOT WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED`.